# How to group by a select number of fields in an RDD looking for duplicates based on those fields

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Scala and Spark. I am working in the Spark Shell.
I need to Group By and sort by the first **three fields** of this file, looking for duplicates.  If I find duplicates within the group, I need to append a counter to the **third field**, starting at "1" and incrementing by "1", for each record in the duplicate group.  Resetting the counter back to "1" when reading a new group. When no duplicates are found, then just append the counter which would be "1".

**CSV File** contains the following:
("00111","00111651",**"4444"**,"PY","MA")
("00111","00111651",**"4444"**,"XX","MA")
("00112","00112P11",**"5555"**,"TA","MA")

**val csv = sc.textFile("file.csv")**
**val recs = csv.map(line => line.split(",")**

If I apply the logic properly on the above example, the resulting RDD of recs would look like this:
 ("00111","00111651",**"44441"**,"PY","MA")
 ("00111","00111651",**"44442"**,"XX","MA")
 ("00112","00112P11",**"55551"**,"TA","MA")

Comment: It's a bit "please write my code" as it stands. What have you tried? What approach have you considered?

Comment: Again.  It's not "write my code".  I am new to SCALA.  I was able to identify the duplicates using the following:  var addrDupes = loadAddresses.map(a => (a.field1,a.field2,a.field3)).countByValue.toList  Just can't figure out how to change the field

Comment: It wasn't an accusation, but a problem statement without any code will tend to get interpreted that way. Anyway, you have two answers now, one from me.

Comment: I'll remember to include my code next time.  However my actual code includes 300 Java classes and a much more complex data structure that I'm dealing with.  The example I posted was the most basic aspect of what I am trying to do without including all of the other stuff.

Answer (score 3):

How about group the data, change it and put it back:

```
val csv = sc.parallelize(List(
  "00111,00111651,4444,PY,MA",
  "00111,00111651,4444,XX,MA",
  "00112,00112P11,5555,TA,MA"
))
val recs = csv.map(_.split(","))
val grouped = recs.groupBy(line=>(line(0),line(1), line(2)))
val numbered = grouped.mapValues(dataList=>
      dataList.zipWithIndex.map{case(data, idx) => data match {
          case Array(fst,scd,thd,rest@_*) => Array(fst,scd,thd+(idx+1)) ++ rest
      }
    })
numbered.flatMap{case (key, values)=>values}
```

Comment: I think (but I'm not sure) that its the first 3 fields that need to be unique, not just the third. OP, please confirm

Comment: That is correct.  First three fields need to be unique.  Justin's solution will not work.  Thank you.

Comment: Yep, looks good. We've ended up with pretty much the same now, just slight stylistic differences

Answer (score 2):

Also grouping the data, changing it, putting it back.

```
 val lists= List(("00111","00111651","4444","PY","MA"),
("00111","00111651","4444","XX","MA"),
("00112","00112P11","5555","TA","MA"))

val grouped = lists.groupBy{case(a,b,c,d,e) => (a,b,c)}
val indexed = grouped.mapValues(
               _.zipWithIndex
                .map {case ((a,b,c,d,e), idx) => (a,b,c + (idx+1).toString,d,e)}

val unwrapped = indexed.flatMap(_._2) 
//List((00112,00112P11,55551,TA,MA),
//     (00111,00111651,44442,XX ,MA),
//     (00111,00111651,44441,PY,MA))
```

Version working on Arrays (of arbitary length >= 3)

```
val lists= List(Array("00111","00111651","4444","PY","MA"),
Array("00111","00111651","4444","XX","MA"),
Array("00112","00112P11","5555","TA","MA"))
val grouped = lists.groupBy{_.take(3)} 
val indexed = grouped.mapValues(
      _.zipWithIndex
       .map {case (Array(a,b,c, rest@_*), idx) => Array(a,b,c+ (idx+1).toString) ++ rest})

val unwrapped = indexed.flatMap(_._2)  
// List(Array(00112, 00112P11, 55551, TA, MA),
//      Array(00111, 00111651, 44441, XX, MA),
//      Array(00111, 00111651, 44441, PY, MA))
```

Comment: Thank you Paul!  This worked.  Just have to make it work with an unlimited number of fields.  Thanks again.

Comment: That should be straightforward if you use split and so Arrays (as in your sample code) and not tuples (as in your example list). Also simplified it a  bit,  I was making things overcomplex

Comment: And simplified again. Hat-tip to @JustinPihony for the zipWithIndex idea

Comment: version for arrays added

Comment: Downvoted as this is the SAME exact thing I posted. You only tweaked what the grouping was....

Comment: Well, it is now, yes. After you changed your code too. Follow the history, though, it didn't start that way